# Which non-faction battleships have the best chance to get into an incursion fleet?

Tags: eve-online

I've never flown in an incursion, but I'm thinking about trying it out in the near future. From what I've heard incursion fleets are rather picky about which ships they take, with rather expensive navy or pirate faction ships being preferred.

I don't want to risk a billion or more for trying it out, I'd like to try it in a common T1 battleship first. I haven't had any use for a battleship so far and haven't invested any significant amount of training into any specific race or weapon system at the BS size.

From what I understand so far, missile ships are not in favor and shield tanking is far more common than armor tanking in incursion fleets.

Which battleships are in demand for incursions? Which one should I learn to have a good chance of getting into incursion fleets?

Comment: Have you popped into The Valhalla Project's channel in game? They should be able to help you with a good start and a fit for whichever BB then need more of.

Comment: You should take a look at [that website](http://incursions.nexsoft.de/), you'll find some usefull advices & links. (Most of it is about shield tanked ships, i don't have links for armor fleets atm...)

Answer (score 1):

you can try Abbadon or Apoc also Mael is ok all should be t2 fitted (appart of guns) good EHP and omni res above 70%. If yuo can fit it this way you should be ok. Just don't expect to be picked up to fleet oftenly. Every FC will take any t2/t3 ship rather then t1 ofc.

Low cost for you should be navy version BS or Command Ship as a minimum. Sometimes t1 BS will be picked up for sniper role. But only if there is no t2 around.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is the sniper rokh is always useful if you want to try getting into incursions using a T1 ship. Obviously they will pick up faction battleships first. Just stay away from missiles, everyone in incursions always complains about missile boats because they take too long to get get damage on the target.

If you can't afford a faction battleship and just want to test out incursions hop in a logi ship. I always see this recommendation for pilots new to incursions. They are cheap, don't require a ton of training, and always highly sought after in fleets. This should give you an idea of how the incursion community functions and what will be expect of you when you're ready to invest in a faction BS.